# How to svn diff two files in different branch and from two specific revison?

Tags: shell, svn, diff, meld

I can use this get the diff between a specific revision number and latest version for a certain file

```
svn diff -r<revision number> --diff-cmd='meld' <svn_url>
```

But if I have two files, in two different branch, then I want to diff them from two specific revisions. How do I do that without checking out files?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usage :

```
svn diff --diff-cmd meld OLD-URL[@OLDREV] NEW-URL[@NEWREV]
```

reference :

`svn help diff`, 4-th form:

example :

```
 svn diff --diff-cmd meld http://server/project/branches/branch1/file1@15 http://server/project/branches/branch2/file1@27
```